# Call same SUB from multiple buttons in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple buttons (active x) on a spreadhseet in same column but different rows. These buttons capture the start time of an activity.
If button 1 is pressed cell next to it should be populated by current time.
If button 2 is pressed cell next to it should be populated by current time. and so on.....

I have written a SUB in VBA as follows:

```
Private Sub StartTimer_Click()
    Range("I4").Value = Now
End Sub
```

I do not want to repeat this code for each button action. Please let me know how it can be made dynamic.

Comment: Try googling "VBA control array"

Comment: If those are indeed ActiveX buttons (as opposed to Forms buttons), you would have different event handlers for each button anyway, unless you go with the [approach shown by EvR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245920/11683). So if you don't, and you therefore have multiple handlers, the only optimization is then to have same code in all handlers, rather than slightly different code. For that you only need a way to look up the cell to change from the button object. You can code that in the button's name like EvR suggests, or you can use `TopLeftCell` of the button as a landmark to offset from.

Answer (score 3):

A simple WithEvents example:

in a class (named clsButtons):

```
Private WithEvents Bt As MSForms.CommandButton

Property Set obj(b As MSForms.CommandButton)
    Set Bt = b
End Property

Private Sub Bt_Click()
    'uses the right of the name of the CommandButton
    Cells(1 + Right(Bt.Name, 1) * 3, 9).Value = Now
End Sub
```

In the sheetcode (the one with the buttons):

```
Dim myButtons As Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim ctl As OLEObject
    Dim ButtonClass As clsButtons
    Set myButtons = New Collection

    For Each ctl In Sheet1.OLEObjects
        If ctl.progID = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then
            Set ButtonClass = New clsButtons
            Set ButtonClass.obj = ctl.Object
            myButtons.Add ButtonClass
        End If
    Next ctl
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Another way to infer the cell to change from the button would be using the `TopLeftCell` of the button, given that the button is always next to the cell it should change.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a standard module and put the procedure in there.**

While it is possible to share a procedure in a private module, it's best practice to put any shared procedures in a shared module.

In the VBA Editor click `Insert` > `Module`,

Paste into there, and give it a unique name. Using your example you could do something like:

```
Public Sub SetTimeValue()
    Range("I4").Value = Now 
End Sub
```

...then call this public stub from your other one, like:

```
Private Sub StartTimer_Click()
    SetTimeValue
End Sub
```

...and from any other locations where you need to call your code.

I assume that you have more than one line of code for the *actual* procedure you're concerned about, otherwise copying it repeatedly isn't really a concern.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Understanding Scope and Visibility**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/understanding-scope-and-visibility)
- Office Support : [**Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications)
- Chip Pearson : [**Understanding Scope Of Variables And Procedures**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx)
- PowerSpreadsheets : [**Excel VBA Sub Procedures: The Complete Tutorial**](https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-sub-procedures/)
- MVP : [**Cut out repetition using subs and functions with arguments**](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/ProcArguments.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is: I have multiple buttons StartTimer1, StartTimer2, StartTimer3.... How can I call StartTimer_Click() for each button. With each call the cell has to be different. In this example: Range("I4").Value = Now. For 2nd button it could be Range("I7").Value = Now. For 3rd button it could be Range("I10").Value = Now

Comment: If it's really only one line of code (like `Range("I4").Value = Now`) then you don't need any other procedures at all.  Just put the one line as the code for each of the buttons. See the links I provided for more information. The last link might be especially useful to you.