# Selection.Goto from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am using a spreadsheet to capture test cases, and in the process of automating the generation of a Word document for presentation to the business. I can't get the `GoTo` function to work across the files, however.

All of the subs are written in the Excel VBA instance.

Here are the two pertinent subs:

Sub 1

```
Sub CreateTestDocument()
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    Set Wordfile = wordapp.Documents.Open("S:\myPath\myFilename.dotm")
    wordapp.Visible = True
    AddNextCase ("FeatureCases")
End Sub
```

'Sub 2 (called from Sub 1)

```
Sub AddNextCase(Bmark As String)
    Wordfile.Activate
    Wordfile.SelectAllEditableRanges
    ActiveWindow.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=Bmark 'ERROR HERE
    Selection.TypeText "TEST1"
End Sub
```

on the `Selection.Goto` line, I get the error below:

> Run-time error 438:
>   **Object doesn't support this property or method**

I've tried various different approaches to this, but i always hit a blocker on setting my entry point to start putting this text block in, what's the obvious issue i'm missing?

Comment: if you are not using a reference to the `Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library` then the constant, `wdGotoBookMark` will be undefined. Have you included this reference in your project references?

Comment: And how did you declare your variables eg `Wordfile`? Are they declared at all? Are they public? Can you include that in the code of your question please?

Comment: `ActiveWindow` in Excel return the current active window of Excel.

Comment: You might want to use `Wordfile.ActiveWindow.Selection.Goto ...`

Comment: @kari - You need to be aware of the **scope** of objects and variables in VBA (as addressed in Taylor's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244862/8112776)).  I just posted a number of good, related links at the bottom of [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51237280) that you might want to check out (the Chip Pearson [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx), at the least).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that a couple things are addressed:

Make sure that the `wordapp` and `wordfile` objects are defined at the module level. I have shown this below using object type references from the `Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library`.  This will also make sure that any word constants you use are defined.

Then you need to use the `wordapp` context for the `activewindow` call. This is done with `wordapp.activewindow`

```
Private wordapp     As Word.Application, _
        wordfile    As Word.Document

Sub CreateTestDocument()

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set wordfile = wordapp.Documents.Open("FILE NAME")
wordapp.Visible = True
AddNextCase ("FeatureCases")

End Sub

Sub AddNextCase(Bmark As String)

wordfile.Activate
wordfile.SelectAllEditableRanges
wordapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=Bmark    
wordapp.Selection.TypeText "TEST1"

End Sub
```

Comment: same issue for `Selection.TypeText "TEST1"`. This would also assume Excel `.Selection` if not referenced to `wordfile` or `wordapp`.

Answer (score -1):

As per MDN *(paraphrased)*:

> `.ActiveWindow` is an `Application`  property that returns the
>   active window ([Window Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/window-object-excel)).

You can't however apply a method to a property, you need to apply it to a `Window Object` instead. Easiest way of achieving this is to store the window object into a variable.

Additionally, your variables such as `wordapp` or `Wordfile` are presumably objects, since you have `Set` them, but there are nowhere declared in your code.

So your code should look something like this:

```
Private Wordfile as Word.Document
Set Wordfile = CreateObject("word.Application")
Private word as Word.Application
Set word = wordapp.Documents.Open("S:\myPath\myFilename.dotm")
' ... rest of the code
wordapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo '... etc
```

In general I would recommend doing a bit of studying into objects, because it looks like you have some learning gaps *(with all due to respect)*

Comment: With the way that @Karl is using their code, both `wordfile` and `wordapp` need to be defined at the `module` level, which your code does not address. Beyond this, your code goes against convention as you have two separate object declaration blocks where one would both work and be more readable.

Comment: Further, I think that you may have gotten your point across better by providing links to resources where OP could learn more about coding in VBA rather than insulting them. On that note, [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables) may help yout to learn about the module level variables and convetion.

Comment: @TaylorScott I agree Karl's answer is clearer, tis'  was however posted few lines away from my own submission so I said to myself, I'll just post it as perhaps supplementary learning material for the OP. Also, there is a link attached to the MDN (in the brackets for window object). Last but not least, my goal here never was to insult. I even said with all due to respect. I did have the impression OP should genuinely spend more time with OOP techniques before dwelling into more complicated code because it will result in further complications, it was a cautious advice, not an insult.