# Create several buttons that delete a different specific cell without having to code each button

Tags: excel, vba

So I know it sounds confusing, so I have prepared a screenshot to better explain what I mean.

Looking at the screenshot, basically what I am trying to ask is, how can I create a button that will delete only the cells of its same color.

I could do it the simple way with ClearContent which would require me to create a macro for each button.
I am working on a small table with few rows so that is not an issue, however, I want to learn of other more efficient methods so I can maybe apply in the future in case I have to work on a table with hundreds of rows.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Each button to ClearContent of its own color, but without having to create a single macro for each button]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call same SUB from multiple buttons in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237250/call-same-sub-from-multiple-buttons-in-vba)

Comment: Instead of buttons, use `shapes` (use rectangle or rectangle with rounded corners) and use "Assign Macro". To tell the macro which shape (button) was clicked, use `Application.Caller`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each button has the respective color, you could create a macro to receive the color of the button and use the same macro for all buttons (ActiveX button):

```
Sheet1.OLEObjects.Object.BackColor ' to get button color
```

Store this color, then use it in something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498970/11776529)

Comment: Sorry I was vague with the explanation, colors are just for illustrative purposes, the actual table does not have colors

Comment: I see. But you would need some form of button, and ActiveX buttons allow you to set the colour. Otherwise you would need a dictionary of colours with button names as the key to get the colour associated to each button

Comment: "the actual table does not have colors" - probably more useful to describe *your actual use case* than something which has no relation to what you need to do...